# Wpf System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser - MessageHook : Close event

Tags: c++, wpf

I am using a (WPF) System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser and I need to dispose the browser when the user closes the browser that is presented in a wpf usercontrol.

To close the webbrowser you can use the following html:

```
<html>
<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="self.close()">
</html>
```

The code I managed to implement looks like this:

```
this.Browser.MessageHook += Browser_MessageHook;   

IntPtr Browser_MessageHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool      handled)
{
  if (msg == 130 && wParam.ToInt32() == 0 && lParam.ToInt32() == 0 && handled == false)
  {
    this.Browser.Dispose();   
  }

  return hwnd;
}
```

Please give your feedback, advice, how should I write the conditions to handle only the close browser event in a better way?